# Jira SAML Metadata example?

Tags: jira, saml, shibboleth, gluu

I am trying to get Jira Cloud to integrate with my Gluu server for SSO. Everything I have read requires a metadata file from my SP. Jira does not provide that when setting up SAML. They provide SP Entity ID and SP Assertion Consumer Service URL. Does anyone have an example of their Jira metadata file? I asked Atlassian but I havent heard anything from them yet.

Comment: Did you ever get Jira cloud working with Gluu?

Comment: No I did not. I contacted Gluu for help and they basically said use someone else. We ended up using Azure, which costs about $10 a month for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually form your own metadata file if you have the correct parameters (which it looks like you have).

There is a tool here you can use to pass in those parameters and it'll produce the metadata XML. (Metadata is just a structured way of communicating the SP properties).

https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php